# XLib: определить позицию курсора

Tags: linux, xorg

Для вращения камеры в игре я определяю позицию курсора, устанавливаю её в центр окна, и к повороту камеры прибавляю разницу с центром, умноженную на некоторый коэффициент. В WinAPI это работает отлично, но после портирования на `Linux` я переписал весь платформозависимый код, и камера стала дёргаться. Вот как я получаю позицию курсора в `XLib`:

```
point2S ws_get_cursor_pos(handle wnd)
{
    Window root_ret, child_ret; int global_x, global_y; uint mask; //unused
    int rel_x, rel_y;
    XQueryPointer(display, IMPL->window, &root_ret, &child_ret, &global_x, &global_y, &rel_x, &rel_y, &mask);
    return point2S((short)rel_x, (short)rel_y);
}
```

Похоже, что происходят какие-то задержки между кадрами и эта функция возвращает старое значение, но после этого курсор переносится в центр и текущее значение теряется. В итоге камера как будто застревает. Причём, когда `FPS` уменьшается, например, при проверке пополигональных столкновений с объектом, камера двигается практически плавно.
 Это предположение подтверждается ещё и тем, что если не двигать курсор в центр экрана, а просто использовать разность позиций между кадрами, то камера двигается плавно (естественно, пока курсор не упрётся в границу экрана и не остановится).

Answer (score 2):

Я все организовывал по вот [этому](http://www.sbin.org/doc/Xlib/chapt_09.html) ману.

Лагов не ловил.

Хотелось бы побольше кода увидеть, может как на железе завязано?(частота и т.д.)

Comment: Там как-то много всего написано. Как именно делал? Через XQueryPointer или через сообщения? Можно увидеть код?

 Весь остальной код не отличается для других платформ. У меня есть реализации платформозависимого кода также через WinAPI (в Windows и через wine) и Qt (на том же Linux'е) и там всё нормально работает.

 Но на всякий случай напишу: процессор AMD 2 ядра 1.6 ГГц, 6 ГБ оперативной памяти, встроенная карта Radeon HD 6310M.

Comment: Там не много.

Конкретный код скинуть не могу, но приблизительный есть вот тут: http://www.jotschi.de/Technik/2009/12/09/xlib-multiple-window-events-example.html

Петля ожидающая подходящего события. У меня была задача прикрутить к голому OpenGL систему ввода. Не уверен, что вам это подойдет, но...

Вы используете Qt в проекте?